# PHP - CSV to SQL Error - Undefined offset

Tags: php, csv

I'm rather rusty with php and sql and i'm having some issues getting the following code to work. I get the error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAMPi\index.php on line 38
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAMPi\index.php on line 39
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAMPi\index.php on line 40
Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAMPi\index.php on line 41
Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAMPi\index.php on line 42
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAMPi\index.php on line 43
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAMPi\index.php on line 44
Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAMPi\index.php on line 45
```

These errors go on for a few more lines but you get the idea - basically every index # in my CSV file.

I've followed a few tutorials and looked on here for solutions but no one else seems to have the exact issue. It's not the CSV file - it uses standard commas to separate values and I'm sure there is data there because when I run the top part it does a print out of my entire csv file, headers and all. Another thing is how can I get it to not insert the headers of the csv into my database? Sorry to be such a noob. As I mentioned I haven't really done any coding like this in a few years.

Please see my full code below:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("data/20151028_22.csv","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {
  print_r(fgetcsv($file));
  }

fclose($file);

echo "<br><br><br> Hopefully this works! <br><br><br>";

// specify connection info
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$connect)
{
   die('Could not <span id="IL_AD1" class="IL_AD">
    connect to</span> MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
}

$date = date("ymd");

$cid =mysql_select_db('sampi',$connect); //specify db name

define('CSV_PATH','C:/xampp/htdocs/SAMPi/data/'); // specify CSV file path

$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "20151028_22.csv"; // Name of your CSV file - Need to tweak this for date+shop
$csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
$theData = fgets($csvfile);
$i = 0;

while (!feof($csvfile))
{
   $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
   $csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
   $insert_csv = array();
   $insert_csv['Hours'] = $csv_array[0];
   $insert_csv['Total_Takings'] = $csv_array[1];
   $insert_csv['Cash'] = $csv_array[2];
   $insert_csv['Credit_Card'] = $csv_array[3];
   $insert_csv['PLU_1'] = $csv_array[4];
   $insert_csv['PLU_2'] = $csv_array[5];
   $insert_csv['PLU_3'] = $csv_array[6];
   $insert_csv['PLU_4'] = $csv_array[7];
   $insert_csv['PLU_5'] = $csv_array[8];
   $insert_csv['PLU_6'] = $csv_array[9];
   $insert_csv['PLU_7'] = $csv_array[10];
   $insert_csv['PLU_8'] = $csv_array[11];
   $insert_csv['PLU_9'] = $csv_array[12];
   $insert_csv['PLU_10'] = $csv_array[13];
   $insert_csv['Customer_Count'] = $csv_array[14];
   $insert_csv['First_Transaction'] = $csv_array[15];
   $insert_csv['Last_Transaction'] = $csv_array[16];
   $insert_csv['No_Sale'] = $csv_array[17];
   $query = "INSERT INTO csvdata(ID,Date,Hours,Total_Takings,Cash,Credit_Card,PLU_1,PLU_2,PLU_3,PLU_4,PLU_5,PLU_6,PLU_7,PLU_8,PLU_9,PLU_10,Customer_Count,First_Transaction,Last_Transaction,No_Sale)
    VALUES('',".$date.",'".$insert_csv['Hours']."','".$insert_csv['Total_Takings']."','".$insert_csv['Cash']."','".$insert_csv['Credit_Card']."','".$insert_csv['PLU_1']."','".$insert_csv['PLU_2']."','".$insert_csv['PLU_3']."','".$insert_csv['PLU_4']."','".$insert_csv['PLU_5']."','".$insert_csv['PLU_6']."','".$insert_csv['PLU_7']."','".$insert_csv['PLU_8']."','".$insert_csv['PLU_9']."','".$insert_csv['PLU_10']."','".$insert_csv['Customer_Count']."','".$insert_csv['Customer_Count']."','".$insert_csv['First_Transaction']."','".$insert_csv['Last_Transaction']."','".$insert_csv['No_Sale']."')";
   $n=mysql_query($query, $connect );
   $i++;
}
fclose($csvfile);
echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
mysql_close($connect); // closing connection
?>
```

Thanks All :) hopefully I can work this out!

Comment: What does the data look like?  Post about the the first 10 lines, including any header.  Or if you can link to the data where I can download/view it then I can help.

Comment: It seems there was a new line at the end of the CSV. Sorry about that! Thing is the error is now gone but the data isn't being added to the table. My page is simply printing the top array, then saying it's done the SQL stuff.

Comment: Also I'm not sure how I can get it to allow said empty line in future as I'm not the one generating the CSV file. I'm simply using a scheduled task to download it from an SFTP hourly. I think I'm in over my head a little. My main issue now is getting the actual data to populate the table, and making sure it doesn't add the first line of the CSV aka the headers

Comment: Test the $csv_array to be sure it is not blank.  Execute the code only if it is not blank.  Aslo, mysql function are gone in PHP7 so you should use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Also, why do the database values contains period before and after the variable?  Like this: ".$date.", where is $date defined?  And this is wrong: '".$insert_csv['Hours']."'.  You don't need the double quotes at all.